c++ giving error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int'
I tried running a program that made an array, but when I tried to run the array, it returned the error stated in the title.
This was my code
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int len;
    cout<<"How long is your array? ";
    cin>>len;
    int arr[len]={};
    for (int i; i<=len; i++){
        cout<<i;
        arr[i-1]=0;
    }
    return(arr); //error happened here.
}


is an int[] an int?

Also, you never initialize i, just declare it, which is undefined behavior.

I'd recommend finding a good C++ book.

int arr[len]={}; -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their size denoted by a compile-time constant, not a runtime variable.  This should be std::vector<int> arr(len);

return(arr); maybe you wanted to return 0; instead. The return value from main is a success / failure code you send back to the OS.

return (arr)  (or, equivalently, return arr) implicitly converts arr into a pointer - of type int * - with value &arr[0] (the address in memory of arr[0]).   main() returns an int (which is a single integral value) not an int *, hence the diagnostic.      The address in memory of an int is not an int.

Lots of errors in this code, which have already been explained. But I think the real question is what did you expect return arr; to do? If you explain that then someone can show you the right way to do whatever it is that you are trying to do.

If I have to guess then I suspect that this is a case of the common beginner confusion between returning and printing. You expected that returning the array would cause the computer to print it. But that is not how C++ works, returning and printing are two completely different things. If you want to print the array then you should research how std::cout works. That's what you use to print something.

the function is supposed to return an int as you have stated 'int' before 'main()' therefore returning '(arr)' which is a 'int*' is not allowed.
return an int type instead.
